# Attach screenshot to Test Step Result (ITestStepResult) - VSTS

Tags: c#, azure-devops, msdn

I am able to create a new Test Run and update each Test Step status and finally complete the Automated Test RUN. I have used C# library files to do all these to VSTS.

Also I am currently working on attaching screenshot to the Test Step result. I can see that screenshot getting attached to the Test Step under Run tab but the upload was not complete and not able to see the screenshot getting loaded.

Following is the code used to attach screenshot:

```
ITestAttachment attachment = stepResult.CreateAttachment(screenShotPath);
stepResult.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

[Also please find the screenshot attached to understand my problem much better.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21FUF.png)

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

With this code below, it uploads the attachment to test step, when I check the test result, the image isn’t displayed correctly (the same as you), but after a minute, it displays correctly. So, you can check image whether displays correctly now.

```
int testpointid = 56;
            var u = new Uri("https://XXX.visualstudio.com");
            var c = new VssClientCredentials();
            c.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage(storageKind: "VssApp", storageNamespace: "VisualStudio");
            TfsTeamProjectCollection _tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(u, c);
            _tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
            ITestManagementService test_service = (ITestManagementService)_tfs.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
            ITestManagementTeamProject _testproject = test_service.GetTeamProject("{proejct}");
            ITestPlan _plan = _testproject.TestPlans.Find(89);
            ITestRun testRun = _plan.CreateTestRun(false);
            testRun.Title = "apiTest2";
            ITestPoint point = _plan.FindTestPoint(testpointid);
            testRun.AddTestPoint(point, test_service.AuthorizedIdentity);
            testRun.Save();
            testRun.Refresh();
            ITestCaseResultCollection results = testRun.QueryResults();
            ITestIterationResult iterationResult;

            foreach (ITestCaseResult result in results)
            {
                iterationResult = result.CreateIteration(1);
                foreach (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ITestStep testStep in result.GetTestCase().Actions)
                {
                    ITestStepResult stepResult = iterationResult.CreateStepResult(testStep.Id);
                    stepResult.Outcome = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestOutcome.Passed; //you can assign different states here
                    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ITestAttachment attachment = stepResult.CreateAttachment(@"{image path}");

                    stepResult.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    iterationResult.Actions.Add(stepResult);
                }
                iterationResult.Outcome = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestOutcome.Passed;
                result.Iterations.Add(iterationResult);
                result.Outcome = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestOutcome.Passed;
                result.State = TestResultState.Completed;
                result.Save(true);
            }
            testRun.State = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestRunState.Completed;
            results.Save(true);
```